# Refactoring to expose private methods for unit testing

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I have a class that process a string and does many actions on it turn by turn.

Those actions need to be done in a specific order.

Example:

```
public String process(String stringToProcess) throws Exception {

    processedString = process1(processedString);
    processedString = process2(processedString);
    processedString = process3(processedString);
    processedString = process4(processedString);
    ...
    processedString = process10(processedString);
    ...

    return processedString;
}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to refactor this to make it cleaner, but most of all, I want to be able to unit test process1, process2 etc.

Note that process1, 2 etc... can be whether 2 line methods or big ones.

I would need the process methods to be somehow public to test them. Is there a design pattern that would achieve this?

I thought about using enums to achieve this, but I thought it was somehow making it more confusing. This implementation is not the best for sure, but at one glance, you know what's happening.

**Edit**: This approach is not too bad to me, but all the process methods should be private. And I want to unit test them.
I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes), so I can test them even if private, but the first step is to make sure it couldn't be done better.

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/455228/Design-Patterns-3-of-3-Behavioral-Design-Patterns#Chain But maybe it's a kind of overkill for your task.

What I would do is to extract `process1`, `process2` etc to separate classes. Then you can a) test them with unit tests separately b) inject them into your class and use them in `process` method in necessary order.

Take a look also to this post: [Design Pattern for a multi-step algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709181/design-pattern-for-a-multi-step-algorithm) Maybe you will get some ideas from there.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify your "private" methods as package protected. Only classes on same package (but from different source folders, like src/main/java and src/test/java or ... from different projects) can access to theses methods.

```
private void myPrivateMethod(){}
```

would becomes

```
/*no visibility keyword for declaring a method package protected*/
void myPrivateMethod(){}
```